# WebStorm: define the variable/parameter type

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to know if it is possible to give WebStorm the format of my data with an annotation to no longer have the "Unresolved variable" message:

[image]

My code is currently fully functional, it's just WebStorm that puts me in alerts and I'd like to remove them cleanly. I'm currently developing this project in node.js using JavaScript without TypeScript and I don't want to change that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I tried `@typedef` but without success.

Comment: It is possible, if you add a doxygen/"javadoc"-style documentation string to your methods. From there you can specify the return type and properties a la: `* @return [{name: string, value: string}]`. So then in the case of `c`, that type would be inferred from `filtered`, which would need to be inferred from some other source. I believe there's also a type-hint available through line comments (`// someVar: string`). Note this isn't necessarily portable. Show more code.